Changing mouse over grid behavior
How to achieve that mouse over Grid is always an arrow like we see on first image (when mouse is over an item of the grid) and never the the shape we see in the second image (when mouse is over in-between items of the grid).
I tried to use Selectable -> False, Editable -> False but it does not change the behavior.
Grid[Table[x, 10, 10], Spacings -> {1, 1}, Selectable -> False, 
 Editable -> False]





maybe MouseAppearance[Grid[Table[x, 10, 10], Spacings -> {1, 1}, Selectable -> False,    Editable -> False], "Arrow"]?

@kglr Is it also possible to disable the cursor when I click on the grid? There appears a blinking cursor of the mouse although option Selectable is set to False.

As written in the documentation for Selectable, this is an option for cells (or boxes). Therefore: CellPrint[ExpressionCell[Grid[Table[x, 10, 10], Spacings -> {1, 1}], "Output",    Selectable -> False]]

how about Style[Grid[Table[x, 10, 10], Spacings -> {1, 1}], Selectable -> False,   Editable -> False]?
